# I try to build a simple image that uses the alpine linux image and prints "Hello StackOverflow!". What is the issue here?

Tags: docker, docker-build

Windows PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alpine              latest              d6e46aa2470d        13 days ago         5.57MB
alpine/git          latest              a8b6c5c0eb62        2 weeks ago         28.4MB

PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker build C:\dfiles
[+] Building 0.9s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.6s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.8s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount632819289/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

The path of where the dockerfile is stored: C:\dfiles

The code in my Dockerfile.txt:

```
FROM alpine
CMD ["echo", "Hello StackOverflow!"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed To Resolve With FrontEnd DockerFIle.v0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221861/failed-to-resolve-with-frontend-dockerfile-v0)  If your Dockerfile is really called `Dockerfile.txt` this could be the issue

Answer (score 3):

**Simple**

Use just `Dockerfile` with no Extention instead of `Dockerfile.txt`

Comment: Nice & Concise ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The code in my Dockerfile.txt

The file needs to be called "Dockerfile", not "Dockerfile.txt". So remove the file extension from your file and try again.