# How to solve the error in package.json when creating an image?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

In the step 4/6 is showing up an error when I try to create this image in Docker:

```sh
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /app/src

WORKDIR /app/src

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install
#IT WILL COPY THE ENTIRE DIR FORECAST TO /app/src INSIDE DOCKER
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD {"npm",  "start"}
```

the error that shows is:

```
=> ERROR [4/6] COPY package.json .                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [4/6] COPY package.json .:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found: not found
```

Comment: On your host system, is `package.json` in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`, and are you also running `docker build .` from that same directory?

Comment: Have you tried any of these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221861/failed-to-resolve-with-frontend-dockerfile-v0 . Seems like the build statement or Dockerfile capitalization can contribute, which seems odd

Answer (score 16):

I was getting a similar error.

```
failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found: not found
```

For me I included a .dockerignore file and placed many other entries other than node_modules

```
**/node_modules
README.md
package.json
package-lock.json
docker-compose.dev.yml
```

So naturally, its not copying required package.json file, and hence the error.
Silly mistake from my side, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 12):

You can try:

```
COPY ["package*.json","./"]
```

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error when i set Dockerfile and package.json in the same file,
for me it was solved by adding "**/" to the path of the json file like this

```
    FROM node:14.17.3-alpine AS build
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    COPY **/package.json **/package-lock.json ./
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

check the path of package.json, note the package.json relative to the dockerfile's path

Answer (score 0):

For me the `package-lock.json` was a dead symlink, pointing to a non-existent file. When the builder resolved the symlink, the hash could not be computed because the file did not exist. Updating the symlink to reference the correct file solved the issue