# Cant create image/ the Dockerfile (Dockerfile) cannot be empty

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am taking a beginner course and not able to create an image on terminal.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZD1MIHwMBY) is the course I am taking(Sorry, the course is in Japanese course but just for the reference). I am at 1:01:39 where he proceeds to create docker image.

First, the error message contained `Failed to solve with frontend docker file.v0:failed to create LLB definition:the Dockerfile cannot be empty`

I ran below command and managed to get rid of Failed to solve with frontend docker file.v0:failed to create LLB definition ([Failed To Resolve With FrontEnd DockerFIle.v0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221861/failed-to-resolve-with-frontend-dockerfile-v0)):

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
```

Now I'm left with the `Dockerfile cannot be empty`

I saw in some page that people fail to locate because of not capitalized dockerfile but that's not my case.

[image]

I have also tried `-f` on the command to direct file

[image]

Comment: What is the actual command you're running?  Does the file named `Dockerfile` exist in the directory you're passing as the argument to `docker build`?  Can you replace "enter image description here" with these details as text?

Comment: Could you by any chances have forgotten to save you changes on the dockerfile ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I saw that you, don't save your dockerfile, try save changes and run docker build again.

Also saw same issue on github, it could be helpful

Try to change COPY to ADD

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5170

Comment: How do I save the dockerfile? Im a super beginner so still dont know how things work. I changed the COPY to ADD but gave me error on daemon

Comment: Use hotkey ctrl+s

Comment: Got it done!!! Just needed to click the save icon on Visual Studio >< Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In VS-Code unless you save the file, it won't work. So try to save it first and then it will work.I faced the same issue, after saving the file it worked. Maybe at times when file is not saved the terminal consider the previous version of the file.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this worked for me just make an edit (space) then resave and it should work