# Docker image for puppeteer node module

Tags: docker, puppeteer, chromium

I am unable to find official docker image for Puppeteer.

There was [buildkite](https://github.com/buildkite/docker-puppeteer) repo but it is not longer supporting docker image for puppeteer.

I came across this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-run-puppeteer-and-headless-chrome-in-a-docker-container/) but most of the packages mentioned in this article are blocked within my org including chromium executable.

I also used below docker file from https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker but ran into multiple errors during execution:

```
FROM node:14-slim

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# If running Docker >= 1.13.0 use docker run's --init arg to reap zombie processes, otherwise
# uncomment the following lines to have `dumb-init` as PID 1
# ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_x86_64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm init -y &&  \
    npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /node_modules \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /package.json \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /package-lock.json

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser

CMD ["google-chrome-stable"]
```

Got following errors:

```
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there any way to get official or any other up-to-date puppeteer docker image ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work , along  with this you can attach a node project in which you want to use puppeteer and in its package.json add puppteer dependency and run npm i in dockerfile

[https://dev.to/cloudx/how-to-use-puppeteer-inside-a-docker-container-568c#:~:text=Puppeteer%20is%20a%20Node.,js%20image](https://dev.to/cloudx/how-to-use-puppeteer-inside-a-docker-container-568c#:%7E:text=Puppeteer%20is%20a%20Node.,js%20image).

Answer (score 0):

[Hidden and deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73434266/80428) by [@Utopiah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442164/utopiah) worked for me

The [official documentation by Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#running-in-docker) is to use their image in the Github Container Registry `ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest`

In practice you would use it like so

Command line

```
docker pull ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest
```

Some more info on using alternative container registries can be found on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134827/80428)