# Unable to pull public image from Github Container Registry (GHCR)

Tags: docker, github, github-package-registry, github-container-registry

I have pushed an image to Github Container Registry (GHCR) and made it public.
When I try to pull it, I get an error (I've already done `docker login`).

`docker pull ghcr.io/username/reponame:master`

Error I receive:

`Error response from daemon: Head "https://ghcr.io/v2/username/reponame/manifests/master": denied: denied`

Visibility is public:
[image]

I could not find much information about this error, but this post describes the same issue: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27116. However, just waiting didn't work for me.

Comment: In case it helps others: make sure your _package_ is set to public, not just your repo! (I didn't realise packages could be private if the repo is public.)

Answer (score 17):

I cannot comment so I will add a new answer. I am having the very same issue, but the correct command to solve it is:

`docker logout ghcr.io`

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the issue by removing my GHCR credentials:

```
docker logout ghcr
```

Seems like a bug in public images/packages.