# Docker no matching manifest trying to pull python 3.10.1

Tags: python, docker

This was working yesterday morning, then something changed and I can no longer pull python:3.10.1 image:

```
$ docker pull docker.io/library/python:3.10.1             
3.10.1: Pulling from library/python
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

The strange thing is I can still pull python:3.10 latest with success. Anyone know what's going on here? I confirmed a couple of my coworkers also see this behavior.

EDIT: also btw a similar issue occurs running my Dockerfile with this:

```
FROM python:3.10.1

...
```

->

```
docker build -t tagg .
[+] Building 2.4s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                      
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                             0.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                0.5s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10.1                                                                           1.6s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10.1:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:2ec4011ae5f1297c728e1adeb85a9c0640a6b83f6d6b5fc029f254baa631292b: not found
make: *** [branch-build] Error 1
```

Comment: Seems like the issue is with your environment. The tag does exist, so it should pull the image correct. Have you looked at this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries

Comment: hi @JeffGruenbaum, yep I did try that solution out, even with the Experimental mode enabled I had the same issue. for reference I'm on Mac with Docker Desktop.

Comment: Hmm, does the file name have a capital D in ```Dockerfile```? Did you take a look at this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221861/an-error-failed-to-solve-with-frontend-dockerfile-v0

Comment: I hadn't seen that solution but my Dockerfile naming is correct and the build variables didn't seem to fix it. it seems suspicious to me that my environment would cause `docker pull docker.io/library/python:3.10.1` not to work but `docker pull docker.io/library/python:3.10` works fine?

Comment: is it just because 3.10.2 is available so I can only use that now?

Comment: that can't be it, I'm still able to pull python:3.8.5 for instance...

Comment: Correct, that should not be the problem. Does it still show that you have the image locally? Does it display the image if you run ```docker images```

Comment: ```$ docker images | grep 3.10
python                                             3.10                                                     cecf555903c6   23 hours ago        917MB
python                                             3.10.2                                                   cecf555903c6   23 hours ago        917MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to have resolved itself...

```
$ docker pull docker.io/library/python:3.10.1
3.10.1: Pulling from library/python
Digest: sha256:b39f8b98308263406dc266ce9244f2e00f0d367003b401543d39854a10bd2786
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.10.1
docker.io/library/python:3.10.1
```